# Three.js example

Tags: javascript, three.js

I would like to ask how to extract the example of the threejs.org example like this https://saydnaya.amnesty.org/?kind=explore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your browser, press F12 and select the Inspector.

There, look for `/js/src`, you then have all of the scripts available.

Comment: is the data of or JSON is also available?